# Trying to embed hyperlinks for a discord bot with javascript

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I want to create a discord bot that when someone types -ping it then gives out a embeded hyperlink.

current code i have is:

"embed.js"

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');


const client = new Discord.Client();


const prefix = '-';
 
const fs = require('fs');
 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
 
 
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('embed is online!');
});
 
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
    if(command == 'ping'){
        Discord.MessageEmbed.channel.send(exampleEmbed)
    } 
});
 
client.login('NzQ4ODQ3MzYwMjA5MzIxOTg0.X0jYcw.fZjcPUwrpEQPkQyqQdxprCYVH6g');
```

"ping.js"

```
 const Discord = require('discord.js');
 
 
 const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();

    exampleEmbed.setTitle('Some title');
    exampleEmbed.setURL('https://discord.js.org/');


Discord.Message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```

I am trying to follow this:

https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview
with this guide,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUOb9_aAk7U&list=PLbbLC0BLaGjpyzN1rg-gK4dUqbn8eJQq4&index=3

any help or reflections are welcome, but please explain it as if it was 5 year old or a rubber duck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have the correct code so for the embed, but you need to send it using `Discord.Message.channel.send({ embed: exampleEmbed });`

Additionally, I advise you to regenerate your bot token [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications) because it allows for anyone to take control of your bot.

Comment: ty and good call on the token.

it should work but i get this error message everytime I try the command

C:\Users\philip von wowern\Desktop\Discord\embed.js:32
        Discord.Message.channel.send({ embed: exampleEmbed });
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous>